# Canonical form of a second orde pde

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

**Question:**
$$4u_{xx}+12u_{xy}+9u_{yy}-9u=9$$

a)Find canonical form

b)find general solution

**Solution:**
It is parabolic pde.

a)
Firstly I found charecteristic as $\xi=2y-3x$ and I selected $\eta=y$ and I found canonical form as $u_{\eta\eta}-u=1$.

Please help the rest.